# How to get the route name of back screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Before I back to the previous screen, is it possible to get this back name and conditional execute the needed method call?

Answer (score 1):

if you use [Get](https://pub.dev/packages/get), you can get previous route name directly by `Get.previousRoute`.

It implements this by a `NavigatorObserver` (lib/get_navigation/src/routes/observers/route_observer.dart)(https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorObserver-class.html). You can also implement your own observer and maintain the route history.

Comment: Could show a example code how to pass arguments to the specific back screen?

Comment: I assume you are using getx. At first screen, use `final YOUR_RESULT = await Get.toNamed(page);` to get the result. At second screen, use `Get.back(YOUR_RESULT);` to pass the result to previous screen.